# How to return match with a string that contains parentheses in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have part of my code extracting an element from a column `Ranks` by matching a string `name` with elements in another column `Names`:

`rank = df.loc[df['Names'].str.contains(name), 'Ranks'].iloc[0]`

The code is working as intended except for some few cases when `name` contains parentheses.

For example, it will cause an error for `name = Banana (1998)`.

I understand that str.contains might not be the best method here, but I have looked around and don't seem to have found any other post asking about the same problem so I can work my way from there.

A sample of the df can be reproduced with:

`data = [['Apple', 10], ['Banana (1998)', 15], ['Banana (2000)', 14]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Names', 'Ranks'])`

Comment: What is the error? In the meantime try `str.contains(name, regex=False)`

Comment: You might have spaces so you should chain a str.strip `df.loc[df['Names'].str.strip.str.contains(name)` what is name BTW a list or a variable?

Comment: @DanielMesejo The first error is ``sre_constants.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 8``. I have tried ``str.contains(name, regex=False)`` and it gives me an ``IndexError``

Comment: What happens if `name` is not in `df['Names']`?

Comment: @Datanovice name is a variable. I need to have different values for ``rank`` for different ``name`` like ``name = "Banana (1998)"`` and ``name = "Banana (2000)"`` for example.

Comment: @DanielMesejo I get an IndexError in that case. But I have checked and it is indeed in ``df['Names']`` if I try ``df['Names'].str.contains('Banana')``. It will however not work if I try ``df['Names'].str.contains('Banana (1998)')``. And as I already commented, I need to differentiate between "Banana (1998)" and "Banana (2000)".

Comment: Could you add  sample of your df? Without an actual sample of the data producing the error is really difficult to know what is happening. It'll be very useful if you could add a sample that reproduces the error

Comment: @DanielMesejo I edited the question to add a code that reproduces sample of the df

Comment: Do you get the same error on that df? I cannot reproduce it

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.25

Comment: @DanielMesejo Thank you for your help, but the error has been solved for me by following the answer that I have selected below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use `str.contains`, you need to escape `'('` and `')'` in `name` because they are special chars in regex as follows

```
name = 'Banana \(1998\)'
df['Names'].str.contains(name)

Out[655]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: Names, dtype: bool

df.loc[df['Names'].str.contains(name), 'Ranks']

Out[659]:
1    15
Name: Ranks, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 9):

There's [regex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) argument. Solution without changing base string:

```
df.loc[df['Names'].str.contains(name, regex=False), 'Ranks']
```